# how to use drupal mail functionality from external php file (sub folder)?

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-7

I have developed a separate functionality using core php in a sub folder of my drupal site (assume something like `mysite.com/myfolder/myfunc.php`).

Now i want to send email as same like how drupal site send it.

Since this is not custom module i can't use `hook_mail`. Or is there any possibility to achieve this?

How to use drupal mail functionality from core php (sub folder of the site)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way is create a module but if needed you can use

```
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
/**
Write your code here
use PHP core, drupal core and contrib functions
**/
```

Comment: okay. To send email i need use `hook_mail` and then `drupal_mail` functions. But mine is not a module. that is all written in core php. What i can do in that case?

Comment: Oh sorry. We can use any name as module name. I used as 'test'. I referred http://dropbucket.org/node/308 and it is working fine except it has to be send as html. That i can check later. But using drupal_mail is just work fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the @AZinkey. One way is to include drupal's bootstrap and have all drupal's features available, like he explained. But better way would be to define your page from Drupal. Check out drupal's hook_menu function:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x

Like explained there:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['abc/def'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
  );
  return $items;
}
function mymodule_abc_view($ghi = 0, $jkl = '') {

  // ...
}
```

.. you can easily define you custom page. All you need is path to page (that "abc/def") and function that will deliver page content ("mymodule_abc_view").

Comment: But there is no module. The page i have written is core php.

Comment: Create one. That's not hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

For the reference I have placed the code here. It may be full code, but that might help someone.

```
//These lines are to use drupal functions
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', 'Your/drupal/path');
require_once '../../../includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

//Get the mail content
$email_content = get_mail_content();
$params = array('body' => $email_content);
$key = 'test_email'; //this is the key
$to = 'siddiqxxxxx@gmail.com';
$from = 'support@xxxxx.com';

//use the hook_mail name here. in my case it is 'test'.
$mail = drupal_mail('test', $key, $to, language_default(), $params, $from);
echo "Mail sent";

//using hook_mail. we can use whatever the name we want. Parameters are just fine.
function test_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $language = $message['language'];
  switch ($key) {
//switching on $key lets you create variations of the email based on the $key parameter
    case 'test_email': //this is the key
      $message['subject'] = t('Test Email');
//the email body is here, inside the $message array
      $message['body'][] = $params['body'];
      break;
  }
}


function get_mail_content() {

  $email_to = 'siddiqxxxxx@gmail.com';
  $pos = strpos($email_to, '@');
  $user_name = substr($email_to, 0, $pos);
  $body = '';
  $body .= 'Hi ' . $user_name . '<br>';
  $body .= 'Please find my test email. <br>';
  $body .= 'This is the email body' . '<br>';
  $body .= 'Thanks<br>';
  $body .= 'TestTeam';
  return $body;
}
```